# querying in hierarchical data-structure in database and displaying results

Tags: php, mysql

I thought to implement advanced commenting system in my website using PHP-MySql. I finally settled for a 3-level comment-reply system for this purpose.
Well, for that purpose I came across [this](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) article to implement the data-structure of the SQL database.

I planned to use nested set mdoel for the feature I want to use. The structure of the comments are like this-

```
<ul>
    <li>Parent comment</li>
        <ul>
            <li>First reply of parent comment</li>
            <ul>
                <li>reply of the previous reply</li>
                   <ul>
                       <li>reply of the previous reply</li>
                       <li>another reply of the previous reply</li>
                   </ul>
                <li>another reply of the previous comment</li>
             </ul>
             <li>second reply of the parent comment</li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

For this type of structure, I have been playing around with PHP to show the query detecting the parents and its child **uniquely**(for fetching user details associated with each comment) and produce the output in the manner if shown above. Do anyone have idea how to do it. Please help me out.

**EDIT :**

I have a seperate user table in SQL linked to the comment table as `user.id=comment.id`. So considering this, what would be the recommended approach to detect user activity for each comment? I mean, for ex- I want to fetch user name and email for a sub-comment of parent comment 2. Hoow could it be done?

Comment: So there can only be at most three levels in the hierarchy?

Comment: yeah I am stuck to that. But for sake of time, it can be as many levels as it can display. I am only interested in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query from "Finding the Depth of the Nodes", and this PHP code will create the nested lists.

```
$cur_depth = -1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { // Loop through results of query
  if ($row['depth'] > $cur_depth) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    $cur_depth = $row['depth'];
  }
  else while ($cur_depth > $row['depth']) {
    echo "</ul>\n";
    $cur_depth--;
  }
  echo "<li>" . $row['comment'] . "</li>\n";
}
while ($cur_depth > -1) {
  echo "</ul>\n";
  $cur_depth--;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't make the comment specific to any user. I said I also do have to fetch user details for each comments

Comment: Just add additional joins to the query to get information from the user table, etc. Then replace `$row['comment']` with whatever formatting you want to do for all the fields.

Comment: could you please edit your answer commenting out the purpose of variables and where they came from? i mean i can guess, but for sake of knowledge base, could you please?

Comment: I just edited my answer to show that it's looping through the results of a query -- the for-loop was left over from my testing with manually-created data. The variables just come from the result of the query on the web site you referenced, except that instead of its `name` column I used `comment`. But you can use any columns you want, as well as additional columns that you get from other tables that you join with. This is just a basic outline, you need to fill in all your application-specific details.

Comment: well, then I think my root problem is over. Now only algorithm left is to decide when the comment-reply system should be stopped for a n-level commenting. You solved my 80% problem. thanks